# How many hybrid connections does Azure relay support

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I find that I can use Azure relay to set up a bidirectional connection between cloud service and local service. But I can not find any information about the question "**how many hybrid connections does Azure relay support?**" in azure website. Does anyone know it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-faq#quotas) says that the maximum number of concurrent relay listeners is **2000**. When exceeded,

> Subsequent requests for additional connections are rejected and an exception is received by the calling code.

This is a system-wide limitation.